# Slim - Preserve blank lines between code blocks in HTML output?

Tags: slim, slim-lang

Slim's "pretty" output currently produces a stream of indented html, which is great but it is hard if I give the code over to people who only edit html.

Is there any way to include blank lines in the html code at points I want?

Answer (score 0):

there is no chance to add blank lines between html code in slim. closest solution to your case are adding comment such `// start div` and `// end div` but this is really painful